# How can I get substring of Page URL in AEM Dispatcher?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, aem

I have to write a Rewrite URL where I have to take substring of the page URL.

For example:
Page URL we access
https://www.example.com/test/url/need-substring-from-page-url123

Expected URL:
https://www.example.com/test/url/url123

Comment: What do you need from .htaccess?
I haven't got any idea for writing rewrite rule for above usecase

Comment: I got this regex ([^-]+$) which will give last word after the - seperator.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below rewrite URL to get the substring

RewriteRule ^/test/url/(.*)-([[0-9]+])$ /test/url/$2 [PT,L]